# Openshift: Uploading File not possible / Sending emails not possible

Tags: angularjs, spring, sendmail, openshift, multipart

I have a small web project where I use openshift as a service for a test system.

Now I got 2 problems:

1) I have a form in which a user shall upload a picture. For that I use multipartfile. **But the file upload just doesn't work, while it does locally under dev**.
So now I ask myself if I need to configure something on the server. But I couldn't find out what (and why).

2) I am sending emails after a certain action. Which again runs perfectly fine under development, **but not using my test system on openshift**. If I remember correctly it was a 415 error, I have to repeat the test at home to look it up.

---

I can't give more information right now as I'm not yet home, but I don't think that much code is needed as it all works fine testing it locally.

I post this question rather for a quick answer like **"uuh yeah, for openshift applications you need to configure it first for doing those things: here and there, make this and that and read here"** which I oversaw.

I hope someone can give me some hints, I don't get why it all works locally but not on a test system.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer:
Make sure your file uploads are being sent to your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` and for email check out this post https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/send-mail-through-openshift-using-gmail or use something like SendGrid which is free in the [OpenShift Marketplace](https://marketplace.openshift.com/apps/9628#!overview).

If those don't help, posting some application logs will be really helpful

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found out that I actually got an entire different problem which might is probably the root problem of all: I can't send payload over POST requests. Maybe you could you take a look [>here<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894284/openshift-415-erorr-restful-communication-with-payload-not-possible)? I created a new question instead editing this one..